# How optimise code to get rid of all my multiple else-if conditions?

Tags: java

This My DAOImple class::::

here i have two drop down boxes like 
1'st box options are ALL,in pool,out of pool.
2ed box option are ALL,active,inactive,Frozen,Baried,Delete.

---

```
public class FleetDetailsDAOImpl22 extends CustomJdbcDaoSupport implements FleetDetailsDAO {

@Autowired
private DataManager dataManager;
/** This method is called for getting all the vessels. */

/**
 * @param vesselStatus
 * @param poolStatus
 * @param poolid
 */

@Override
public List<FleetDetails> getFleetDetails(String vesselStatus,
        String poolStatus, int poolid, String fromDate, String toDate)throws CustomException {

List<FleetDetails> fleetList =new ArrayList<FleetDetails>();
String poolStatusValue = null;
String vesselStatusValue = null;
String displayFlag = null;

/*---check for poolStatus---------*/
if(poolStatus.equals("yes")) {
    poolStatusValue = "Y";
} 
if(poolStatus.equals("no")) {
    poolStatusValue = "N";
}
if(poolStatus.equals("all")) {
    poolStatusValue = "ALL";
}
/*---check for vessel status---------*/

if(vesselStatus.equals("active")) {
    vesselStatusValue = "Y";
    displayFlag = "Y";
}
if(vesselStatus.equals("inactive")) {
    vesselStatusValue = "N";
    displayFlag = "Y";
}
if(vesselStatus.equals("frozen")) {
    vesselStatusValue = "F";
    displayFlag ="Y";
}
if(vesselStatus.equals("buried")) {
    vesselStatusValue = "B";
    displayFlag = "B";
}
if(vesselStatus.equals("pending")) {
    vesselStatusValue = "P";
    displayFlag = "P";
}
if(vesselStatus.equals("delete")) {
    vesselStatusValue = "D";
    displayFlag = "D";
}
if(vesselStatus.equals("all")){
    vesselStatusValue = "ALL";
}

try {

    if(poolStatusValue.equals("Y") && vesselStatusValue.equals("ALL") ){

        String fleetDetailsQuery = dataManager.getQuery("FLEET_DETAILS", Queries.QUERY_GET_FLEET_DETAILS_ALL_NONPOOL);
        Object[] params = new Object[] { poolid, poolStatusValue };
        fleetList = getJdbcTemplate().query(fleetDetailsQuery,params, new FleetDetails.FleetDetailsRowMapper());
    } 
    else if(poolStatusValue.equals("ALL") && vesselStatusValue.equals("ALL")) {
        String allVesselsQuiry = dataManager.getQuery("FLEET_DETAILS",Queries.QUERY_GET_POOL_NONPOOL_VESSELS);  
        Object[] params = new Object[] { poolid };
        fleetList = getJdbcTemplate().query(allVesselsQuiry,params, new FleetDetails.FleetDetailsRowMapper());
    } 
    else if(poolStatusValue.equals("N")){
        String nonpoolVesselsQuiry = dataManager.getQuery("FLEET_DETAILS", Queries.QUERY_GET_NONPOOL_VESSELS);
        Object[] params = new Object[] { poolid, vesselStatusValue,poolStatusValue, displayFlag };
        fleetList = getJdbcTemplate().query(nonpoolVesselsQuiry,params, new FleetDetails.FleetDetailsRowMapper());
    } 
    else if(poolStatusValue.equals("Y")){
        String fleetDetailsQuery = dataManager.getQuery("FLEET_DETAILS", Queries.QUERY_GET_FLEET_DETAILS);
        Object[] params = new Object[] { poolid, vesselStatusValue,poolStatusValue, displayFlag };
        fleetList = getJdbcTemplate().query(fleetDetailsQuery,params, new FleetDetails.FleetDetailsRowMapper());
    }
    else {
        String fleetDetailsQuery = dataManager
                .getQuery("FLEET_DETAILS",Queries.QUERY_GET_STATUS_VESSELS_FOR_BOTH_POOL_NONPOOL);
        Object[] params = new Object[] { poolid, vesselStatusValue,displayFlag };
        fleetList = getJdbcTemplate().query(fleetDetailsQuery,params, new FleetDetails.FleetDetailsRowMapper());
    }

} catch(Exception e) {
    e.getMessage();
}


    return fleetList;
}
```

Comment: If you're using if statements and String.equals, do it like this: "yes".equals(poolStatus) - this won't crash when poolStatus is null

Comment: Why are you using Strings for your status at all? Considered using classes or enums and shift some logic there?

Answer (score 0):

you have used multiple if conditions for checking the value of multiple instead of if elseif so that if one condition succeed it doesn't check for next if condition. And, in order to avoid such confusion it is always better to use "SWITCH CASE" statment.